An outcast, a small town, an abused kid and baseball
Saw a movie when I was younger, think it was from the USA, probably in the 90s though it could have been a re-run at that point, it's been driving me nuts lately trying to remember what it was, I only remember a sequence of scenes.
Basically as far as I know an outcast, (possibly ex con though not sure) moves to smaller town, the part I remember is that he is coaching kids (teens) baseball and one of them is being abused by his dad, the kid slides at one point during practice and is clearly hurt and the coach thinks it's his leg but the best friend of the abused kid says to the coach 'it's not his leg' the coach then figures it out, pulls the kid aside and lifts up the back of his shirt to realise he's being abused. He then goes to confront the dad who is by his car, outside his house and beats him up.
The only other scene I remeber is the two friends are then chatting at the abused kids house some time later and the friend asks how the dad has been and I think the abused kid says something like 'he's been like the easter bunny' or 'nicer than the easter bunny' since the guy attacked him. For some reason I think one of them may have had red hair but I'm not positive on that.
I know that's really vague but if it rings a bell for anyone it would be great to finally learn the name of the film as for some reason the easter bunny comment got stuck in my head and it's driving me crazy trying to figure it out! I only ever saw that tail section so don't know much about what happened earlier. I think at the end the coach character is driven out of town or has to leave, but again I don't remember that too clearly, sorry I don't have more info! 

I remember this movie as well ... though not coming up with the title or actors here. Your description is good enough for someone to figure this out.

I think you want The Man from Left Field with Burt Reynolds and Reba McEntire from 1993:

After taking a job managing a little league team, a homeless man inspires the kids to reach for it all and they inspire him to reclaim his life.

He beats up the abusive father of one of the kids. Later, after the kid is asked how things are at home, he remarks:

It's like living with a 212 pound Easter Bunny.

Here's a preview:




Yes thank-you so much, that looks like the one! You don't know how crazy that's been drivng me, really appreciate the quick response and the great film knowledge :)

@Dressmaker No problem! Don't forget to click on the check mark to mark this as solved.
